# Is using CSS' zoom property for desktop responsiveness a good idea?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend

Is it a good idea to use CSS' `zoom` property for responsiveness instead of manually resizing every element on the webpage in certain screen sizes? This will obviously not work on mobile because it's a whole different layout but it would work for smaller desktop screens. Are there any drawbacks to this (other than Firefox lacking support for the `zoom` property)?

For example -

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1279px) {
  body {
    zoom: 80%;
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time, have a nice day! ✌️

Comment: I’m not sure what you are aiming for here. If the user makes a small viewport are they to get the squished version or the ‘mobile’ version? Whatever the answer to that, is there a reason for not making the styling responsive in the first place, e.g. using units like vmin and % rather than absolute units like px?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it bad idea, because this property do not supported in all browser

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).